# How to Parse an XML Expression in java

Tags: java, xml

Suppose I have an XML statement as below:

```
<expression>
<refobj>[Sales Volume (Actual)]</refobj> - <refobj>[Sales Volume (Target)]</refobj>
</expression>
```

How can I parse this expression in Java?
My Java output should be a String :

```
[Sales Volume (Actual)]-[Sales Volume (Target)]
```

I am parsing my XML file to java using DOM parser.

Comment: Can you post your code using DOM parser?

Comment: You would use a `DocumentBuilderFactory` to create a `DocumentBuilder`, and then use that to parse the XML into an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Document`.  What have you written so far?

Comment: Hi, I am able to parse all the normal XML tags in Java, but this is an expression. I know how to retrieve [Sales Volume(Actual)] and [Sales Volume(Target)], but then how should I retrieve the minus sign from the XML expression in java?

Comment: Is dropping the whitespace around the hyphen intentional, and part of the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to grovel around the nodes in the DOM in this way, you can use a simple XPath expression: normalize-space(/expression).